# How secure are the default repositories of Fedora, CentOS, and Debian?

Tags: security, repository, distributions

**UPDATE:** this question has, thankfully, been thoroughly answered over on infosecurity:
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/139203/112311

I have struggled to find info on what kind of measures are in place, for the most popular distributions, before a package is added to a repository.

I understand that package integrity is verified from repository to user, but I am specifically wondering about when/how it is checked, from a security perspective, from developer to repository. Are there scripts run on new submissions ? Or machines that are frequently rolled back and used solely to test packages and what they do ?

Apple's App Store, for example, has accidentally hosted malware after developers used an unofficial source of `xcode`.

Comment: There probably isn't a single answer, so this is likely too broad.  [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Package_Review_Process) is the process for Fedora though, I assume you can find similar ones for whatever platform you like

Comment: i had a quick look though it seems to talk more about the process of adding a package, on a practical and orderly level, as oppose to much emphasis on security.